# C Programming and Matrix multiplication output issue

Tags: c, matrix

I'm currently learning C programming, to better my understanding of matrices in C I've tried to make this program.
I seem to be having problems with the output, as you can see the program has 3 functions. 
The first one allows you to input the values for the array and then displays it. The second function performs the multiplication and the last should display the output of the multiplied matrix. 
However the output is strange. Here is my code. The output is just below the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_matrix(int m2[][3] )
{
    int i, j;
    printf("input values for matrix in order of rows first \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {       
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        { 
            scanf("%d",&m2[i][j]);          
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", m2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void multiply_matrices(int m1[][3], int m2[][3] ,int m3[][3])
{
    int i, j, k; 

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                m3[i][j] +=m1[i][k]*m2[k][j]; 
            }
        }
    }
}

void write_matrix(int m3[][3] )
{
    int i, j; 

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", m3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int matrix1[3][3], matrix2[3][3], matrix3[3][3]; 

    read_matrix(matrix1);
    read_matrix(matrix2);

    multiply_matrices(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3);

    write_matrix(matrix3);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output!

```
input values for matrix in order of rows first
1
2
3
2
2
2
1
2
2
1 2 3
2 2 2
1 2 2
input values for matrix in order of rows first
2
1
1
1
2
1
2
1
2
2 1 1
1 2 1
2 1 2
-858993450 -858993452 -858993451       /*This is the multiplied matrix output!*/
-858993450 -858993452 -858993452
-858993452 -858993453 -858993453
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I fear it may be just a silly mistake; if so I'm sorry, but I can't see where I am going wrong at this moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize all elements of matrix `m3` to `0` before performing this operation

```
m3[i][j] +=m1[i][k]*m2[k][j];
```

in function `multiply_matrices`.

Comment: Doh!, This is bad of me, I forgot once a while ago to initialize an array and had problems.I think I will add the ability to choose the size of the matrices now instead of 3x3.                          Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize matrix3 in the function multiply matrix like this

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        m3[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

After this, do the multiplication and everything will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```c
int m3[][]={};
```

It initially stores 0 for all available index of m3